# In elasticsearch, is there some method to reduce the importance of a set of search terms?

Tags: elasticsearch

Ideally, I would like to reduce the importance of certain words such as "store", "shop", "restaurant".

I would like "Jimmy's Steak Restaurant" to be about as important as "Ralph's Steak House" when a user searches for "Steak Restaurant". I hope to accomplish this by severely diminishing the importance of the word "restaurant" (along with 20-50 other words).

Stop words work well for some words, such as "a", "the", "of", etc, but they are all-or-nothing.

**Is there a way to provide a weighting or boost value per word at the index or mapping level?**

I can probably accomplish this at the query level, but that could be very bad if I have 50 words whose impact I need to reduce.

This was a generalized example. In my actual complex solution, I really do need to reduce the impact of quite a few search terms.

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe it is possible to specify a term-level boost during indexing.  [In this thread](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Modification-of-term-weight-td1449157.html), Shay mentions that it is possible in Lucene, but that it's a tricky feature to surface through the API.

Another [relevant thread](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Handling-tag-quot-weights-quot-td1395562.html), suggesting the same thing.  Shay recommends trying to sort it out using a custom_score query:

> I think that you should first try and solve it on the search side. If you know the weights when you do a search, you can either construct a query that applies different boosts depending the tag, or use custom_score query.
>
> Custom_score query is slower than other queries, but I suggest you run and check if it's ok for you (with actual data, and relevant index size). The good thing is that if its slow for you (and slow here means both latency and QPS under load), you can always add more replicas and more machines to separate the load.

[Here is an example of a custom_score query](https://gist.github.com/913260#gistcomment-26720) that boosts on a somewhat-similar term level (except it's for a special field that only has one category term, so this may not apply).  It might be easier to break the script out into a native script, instead of using mvel, since you'll have a big list of words.

As an alternative, perhaps add a [synonym token filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/synonym-tokenfilter.html) that interchanges words like "shop", "restaurant", "store", etc?

Comment: Thanks for aggregating this information. Very useful! I also like your idea of using a synonym token filter. I could harness a synonym filter to "merge" words that I would like to reduce. Example: Shop, Restaurant => reduce_20_percent. Then, I can probably just make sure the token reduce_20_percent gets reduced via custom_score